# Can a site collection admin or site owner change the external sharing setting for a site (Modern Team or Modern Communication)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, external-sharing, sharepoint-admin-center

Currently using the Office 365 admin or SharePoint admin, we search for a SharePoint site inside the SharePoint online admin center (either classic, Modern Team or Modern communication) and define its external sharing settings as follow:

[image]

but my question is, if the site collection admin or site owner can modify this external sharing settings? even if they do not have access to the SharePoint admin center? is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Microsoft documentation: [Change the sharing settings for a site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-external-sharing-site),

> You must be a Global Administrator or SharePoint Administrator in Microsoft 365 to change the sharing settings for a site (previously called a "site collection"). Site owners aren't allowed to change these settings.

I tried using Site Collection Administrator & Site Owner user account and they cannot change the external sharing settings for the site.

Comment: do you think they can do it using Power Shell?

Comment: No, PowerShell will also require the same permissions. While using PowerShell user should be either global admin or SP tenant admin AND Site collection administrator.

Comment: Here's documentation related to using PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps#description